# Apply changes to components added on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
 <SqlEditor  style={{width: "100%"}} title="A" disabled={disabled}/>
```

and on every button press, this component gets added to a list.

```
    const addSqlEditor = () => {
        setSqlEditorList( v =>[...v, <SqlEditor  style={{width: "100%"}} disabled={disabled}
        />]);
    }
```

`<div> { sqlEditorList } </div>`

when i press the button a few times and added some editors to the screen, i want to

```
setDisabled(true)
```

but this doesn't work on the components already added (sqlEditorList), only the components added after this will
have a `disabled` state of `true`.

how do i apply the changes to the existing `sqlEditorList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you save elements in a state, which won't detect other state changes, you can use [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) instead.

```
const sqlEditorList = useMemo(() => (
    <SqlEditor  style={{width: "100%"}} disabled={disabled} />
), [disabled])
```